# How to implement old film effect?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to implement an old film effect on pictures. Does anyone know a library or even the rare maths involved? I'd like it to cope with red shift for over-exposition and the rest. Even if you don't know the maths or a library, a pointer to any technical doc will be appreciated.

---

Clarification: I need to write these routines for a project of my own. I'd like to know what kind of processing has to be done and how. Doesn't matter the environment and system, I just need some hint on how process RGB data

Comment: You should try to better describe what you want to do, if you expect a good answer. Platform, language used, context, file format, etc...

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel,  Photoshop has some great color balancing capabilities.  You can also use javascript in photoshop and there are capabilities to replay actions without any coding at all

Comment: I don't want to use this in PS. I need it for my own app...

Comment: Do you mean sepia tone or something else?

Comment: I mean something like magicbullet

Answer (score 1):

You mention Magic Bullet from Red Giant Software in your comments.  There's an impressive amount of image processing know-how behind the development of Magic Bullet.  You'd probably have an easier time implementing a host interface for After Effects or Final Cut Pro plug-ins and using Magic Bullet.

If you want to see some source code in action, examine the open source projects that do image processing like GIMP, CinePaint, FreeFrame, etc.

Comment: I'm really interested in those topics. Do you have any pointers. I can't use plugins as I'm targeting Java

Answer (score 0):

You could try with as3 bitmapdata noise function http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#noise%28%29

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a plugin for [Paint.Net](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewforum.php?f=16), I'm sure you could just use that dll in your program.  Is [this](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?p=43441#43441) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Rare maths?

Create several different transparent PNGs with scratch and dust marks on it.  Take a pic, adjust the hue, saturation and brightness (algorithms for this aren't that complex) to fade out the pic, then overlay one to many of the scratchy PNGs.  The more scratch/dust PNGs you have, the more random the effect you can create.

Not much math here IMHO.

Comment: Not really, that's too simple and not what I want. I think I must implement Exposition simulation and other alghorithms, it's not that simple...

Comment: @gotch I think you must do more than you must.